# How can I monitor processes running at a CPU thread of a Hyperthreading CPU?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-usage

My system is a network equipment, it uses Intel Hyper Thread processor and it runs Centos Linux. I can see /proc/cpuinfo has 2 processors, I assume they are actually 2 CPU threads, not 2 CPU cores.

Now when I run "top", I can see all the processes running at both CPU threads. My question is, how can I monitor process running at only 1 CPU thread?

Pressing "1" can show more CPU info from

```
%Cpu(s):  2.4 us,  1.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
```

to

```
%Cpu0  :  3.1 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.8 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  1.7 us,  2.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.6 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

So looks like top does breakdown CPU threads, but I do not figure out how to make it to show processes by each or 1 CPU.

Answer (score 0):

`ps -o pid,sgi_p,cmd -p [pid]` (for a specific `pid`) or `ps -eo pid,sgi_p,cmd` (for all `pid`s) will show which processor specific processes (`pid`s) are running on or `*` if the process is neither running nor runnable (though, remember that processor assignment may be transient).

A more useful `ps` example (with lots of outputs) may be:

```bash
ps -eo pid,ppid,nlwp,tid,user,group,sgi_p,pcpu,pmem,stat,wchan:32,start,cputime,tty,cmd
```

Check out the `ps` manpage under `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS`.